Do you use a comma after the word "and" when it is the first word in a sentence and then you address someone?
Please know that my question is not regarding what I write.  It's what I hear as a court reporter and put into written form.  Also know this question pertains to how an answer (A.) begins.  There's no option not to have "and" as the first word in the sentence.  See below for explanation.
A. And, Ms. Doe, did you see the accident happen?
or
A. And Ms. Doe, did you see the accident happen?
I prefer the first example, partly because of the rule to put commas around names when the person is being addressed and partly because the second one starts as if you are referring to Ms. Doe, not addressing her.   But when I'm reading books, I more often see the second example used.

You are mixing two standards. 1 - Your job requires that you transcribe what you hear without editing: Uh, um, but, uh, yeah I guess. Yeah, I guess. Oh yeah. I guess." 2 - But now you're asking if it's good English. How can you follow both?

Was there a spoken pause with its consequent intonation change compared with just powering on through breathlessly?

The days are thankfully over when there would be a binding rule about this (commas with introductory element and/or commas with parentheticals such as vocatives). The first thing to check is • Does inclusion or omission of the comma lead to loss of clarity in meaning? The second is • If not, does inclusion or omission of the comma lead to a different, unwanted meaning? The third is • Again if not, does inclusion or omission of the comma indicate the cadence it is desired to communicate (tchrist's comment)? Here, you are free to choose between one pause and two.

@EdwinAshworth - Why does no one ever tell me this stuff? I'm still using the Oxford comma...

@FlorenceN: The Oxford comma is required to give the intended sense in certain cases, while its use forces an unintended sense in others. [Joe Kessler / Adam Katz]

@EdwinAshworth - That was sweet. Thanks. (I actually like the Oxford comma. I like the amusing results using and not using it produces.

I know how stretched nurses are with patient demands and staffing levels. // Oxford University Press regrettably require the use of the Oxford/listing comma, but the Oxford University style guide disagrees, sanctioning the use of this comma only where it will clarify.
